# IIS and SSL Certificates

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, ssl-certificate

I have the following markup

`<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://www.shoeshow.com/">www.shoeshow.com</a><br/><br/>
<a href="https://shoeshow.com/">shoeshow.com</a><br/><br/>
<a href="https://www.shoedept.com/">www.shoedept.com</a><br/><br/>
<a href="https://shoedept.com/">shoedept.com</a><br/><br/>
<a href="https://www.shoedeptencore.com/">www.shoedeptencore.com</a><br/><br/>
<a href="https://shoedeptencore.com/">shoedeptencore.com</a><br/><br/>
</body>
</html>`

The problem is if you click on www.shoeshow.com that link works and the rest are giving errors **connection is not private**.

I understand a wild card certificate, but would a Subject Alternative Names (SAN) cover the wild card?

https://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=san-ssl-certificates

I need prvent all of these and possibly more URLs from displaying the ugly - Your **connection is not private**

Is there something that can be done on IIS to prevent this or in the DNS records?

Thank you ServerFault community.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your markup, its the SSL certificate on the webservers. Are you the administrator of the web server that hosts these sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your certificate named www.shoeshow.com, you will want to add a SAN for each of the other names you wish to use:

- shoeshow.com
- www.shoedept.com
- shoedept.com
- www.shoedeptencore.com
- shoedeptencore.com

If there are other domain names you wish to add on this same certificate, you will of course need to add those as SANs also.

You will need to work with the certificate vendor to have SANs added to your certificate. They will then reissue you the certificate. You will need to install the newly reissued certificate on your server, replacing the old certificate.

As an example, here are some of the SANs that Google is using on their certificate:

[image]

Comment: What domain did you go to for Google to view the Certificate to show the Subject Alternative Names? --- Disregard I went to https://myaccount.google.com/ and was able to see it.  Thanks again.

Comment: You can also see SANs (and other properties of certificates) just by using your browser. I went to https://google.com, then clicked on the little padlock icon, then choose Certificate Details. You can see expiration date, SANs, etc.